# Adding extra branding to an existing website

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker, branding

I am thinking of introducing a new look and feel for our website. We would like it to co-exist with the existing branding. The style (css/images) seen by the customer depends on a the person logging in to the system. We use spring 3.0 and and have a very simple FreeMarkerViewResolver and servers freemarker pages.

I was wondering if you guys could share how you guys approached or would approach this. Ideally I would like to the views (htmls) to remain untouched but different css/images are served based on the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up implementing a simple solution 1. Have the brand value available in the model at all times 2. Update the directory structure of css and images to include both the brands and brand specific assets. 3. Update the paths to css and images to reflect the changed directory structure. This seems to do the basic job for me

Answer (score 0):

This is not as simple as it might seem. The browser caches stylesheets, so you need to import different stylesheets, or have a naming convention that adds a prefix to every style (e.g .admin.body.h1 .user.body.h1 etc).

I think you will need to modify the views accordingly or (shudder) fudge different locales for each role. Maybe someone else has a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

What about a controller serving the image based on the logged in user (or the users company, or or or)?

Thats easy to do with a response entity result and the only issue would be the client side cache. This you can solve by adding a variable to the requested url. Either as a pathvariable or a requestparameter.